# Build application that can run on desktop as well as web

Tags: .net, silverlight, frameworks, devforce

I am looking for some kind of framework or application tool or 3rd party components that can help me develop application that can run on user's desktop/laptop as well as on the web browser and mobile devices. I want to keep the option open to deploy it on Azure in the future. I looked at IdeaBlade.com and dynamics CRM/XRM and force.com. But looking at other options if anyone can suggest. I want something that can take care of plumbing for me and provide infrastruture so I can focus on business logic. The application that I need to develop need to interface very heavily with office apps and outlook as well as need to have some accounting concepts implemented in it.

Comment: And how is it going to integrate heavily with an Office app from a mobile device? Or from any browser that isnt IE? Even silverlight has poor app-integration options, and is very limited re mobile.. That is **radically** different to integrating desktop apps (specially Windows). Unless you are using a central server that handles all the office stuff... This is a very ambitious task. Good luck with that...

Comment: For integration with outlook, I am thinking of integration at exchange server instead of outlook client. For other office app, it might have to be some central server as you suggest

Comment: @MarcGravell: I think he meant interface, not integrate.  This could be a contact-the-server-only thing, and I don't think would be as hard from a cross-platform standpoint.  IE-only wouldn't surprise me though, as you've mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

(sorry for my bad english)

I do not believe on these "one app running on all devices" thing - maybe one day this will happen but now I think your best bet would be to develop a server solution (eg.: exposing services with WCF) and develop multiple clients that would consume it. Then you can focus on the strong points of each platform, develop natively for mobile devices and have the best experience possible. With silverlight you can use COM automation so integration with office/outlook should not be a problem, here is a nice example that shows [how to automate outlook](http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2009/12/23/silverlight-4-grabbing-emails-from-the-outlook-inbox.aspx) - To ease some of the burdens of mobile dev, for this devices you could use something like (HTML5) [phonegap](http://phonegap.com/) or (C#) [monotouch](http://xamarin.com/monotouch) and [monodroid](http://android.xamarin.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Try extjs framework from Sencha. With this framework you can easy make online app and a offline rund by every browser , offline!! Cheers!